# Windows Server 08 Standalone exe Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 error

Tags: c#, cron, windows-server-2008, oledb

I have a standalone application used for CRON that I deployed to a Windows Server 2008 machine that keeps giving me the error below.

System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

I did some research on the subject and it seems a 64 bit application does not work with the MSJet dll for 64bit. So the solution was to recompile the application and have it targeted for a 32bit machine, however I cannot do that in my project. I looked the in the C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder and found both the msjet40.dll and msjetoledb40.dll files. Is there any other way I can run this application as is or maybe in a compatibility setting since I cant target it to 32 bit when I build it.

Comment: "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `msjet40.dll` or `msjetoledb40.dll` if your application is a 64-bit process. You will have to use the ACE OLEDB 12.0 which is the only real alternative that supports 64-bit process. Your only other option is to compile the application as a 32-bit process.

You can download this driver from: [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en)  and if you are looking for additional information you can find it [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/using-jet-in-64-bit-environments)